# Row operations on already reduced rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say I have a matrix and I reduce a row by say adding another row to it, can I then for example take that row and add/subtract a multiple of it to the already reduced row? further can I carry out a second operation on the already reduced row?

Comment: As long as you perform one operation at a time, you can chain them freely. After a first legal transformation, you obtain a new matrix. This new matrix does not "remember" it came from another. So you can process it as you want.

In fact, those transforms are reversible, provided you remember the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can perform valid elementary operations in any sequence on the rows without changing the solution to the linear system of equations.